# Django app cannot write to log handler; permission denied

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions

I am having a problem with Django 1.6.11, Apache 2.4, mod_wsgi, where the log handler does not have permissions to write to the log file. I realize there are lots of similar questions out there, and most of them are resolved by setting the file permissions correctly. I *believe* the permissions are set up correctly in this case but would be happy to be proven wrong...

From the Apache logs + `ps`, you can see the Apache user is `apache`:

```
[Fri Oct 16 12:47:25.360845 2015] [:error] [pid 33075] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:64316] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'custom': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/producer/logs/producer2.log', referer: https://example.com/

[user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx producer] $ ps auxw | grep 33075
apache   33075  0.8  0.3 445296 27668 ?        Sl   12:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
user     33230  0.0  0.0 112640   964 pts/2    R+   12:47   0:00 grep --color=auto 33075
```

But my file permissions show that `apache` owns the target file and has read / write permissions:

```
[user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx producer] $ ls -al logs
total 4
drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache apache   69 Oct 16 12:45 .
drwxr-xr-x. 20 root   root   4096 Oct 13 16:50 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache    0 Oct 16 12:45 producer2.log
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache apache    0 Oct 16 12:41 producer.log
-rw-rw-r--.  1 apache apache    0 Oct 13 16:50 test_producer.log
[user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx producer] $ pwd
/var/www/producer
```

Changing permissions to `777` on the log file does not help.

My handlers are configured as such:

```
'handlers': {
    'custom': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/www/producer/logs/producer2.log',
            'mode': 'a',
            'maxBytes': 10000000,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
    },
```

I can change the file in the handler to point somewhere else, but regardless of where I point it and how I change the permissions of the target file / directory, I get the `Permission denied` error. I recall sometimes you have to change the permissions of the parent directory too, but even when I set that to `777` and owned by `apache`, I get the same error.

Am I missing a stupid step somewhere, or have a typo (which would benefit from some fresh eyes)? Are there other possible causes of this problem, which are being masked? I've done this before with other apps and usually can clear it up with file system permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so kind of a random solution, but turns out our IT department is using SELinux to manage kernel-level permissions...which ignored anything I did. Solution -- work with IT to update the SELinux permissions.